# Trying to SUM filtered objects django

Tags: python, mysql, django-models, django-views, orm

guys i'm really new using Django, i'm trying to sum a filtered list of objects by datetime like this SQL

```
SELECT ((select sum(some_col) from some_table WHERE datte> now()-interval 1 day))
```

i tried something like this:

```
inidate = datetime.datetime.now() 
d_date= timezone.now() - timedelta(1)
query = Model.objects.filter(date__range=(d_date,inidate)).aggregate(sum('values'))
```

result>>>

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a [**`Sum`** expression <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#sum), not the [**<s>`sum(…)`</s>** builtin <sup>[python-doc]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), so:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

query = Model.objects.filter(
    date__gte=timezone.now() - timedelta(1)
).aggregate(Sum('values'))
```